# Как правильно удалить файл через javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где у меня ошибка?
В файл `test.php` добавляю:

```
<script>
if(isset($_GET['del']))
{unlink("http://путь_к_файлу_который_нужно_удалить/default.tpl");}
</script>
```

При обращении к `http://мойсайт.ру/test.php?del` файл не удаляется. Что я делаю не так? Благодарю!

Comment: Причем здесь js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через `JavaScript` никак, через `PHP` пожалуйста:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['del'])) {
    unlink("default.tpl");
}
?>
```